# Multiple `ON CONFLICT` in insert query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which have columns like `id, name, start_date, end_date`
and 2 unique constraints
`unique(id, name, start_date)`
and
`unique(id, name, end_date)`

now when I am writing insert query for this table, I have something like

```
insert into table (id, name, start_date, end_date)
values (1, 'test', 'example-start-date', 'example-end-date')
on conflict (id, name, start_date) set something
on conflict (id, name, end_date) set something
```

but getting errors, is this not allowed?

thanks

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) this is not allowed

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on `something`.

- For `DO NOTHING`, the answer is simply to use a single clause without specifying the columns:

  ```
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
  ```

  That can deal with conflicts on multiple unique constraints.
- For `DO UPDATE`, there is no straightforward solution.  [The syntax diagram in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) shows that you can only have a single `ON CONFLICT` clause that determines a single unique index.

  You could use procedural code to do it in the old-fashioned way, for example in PL/pgSQL:

  ```
  DECLARE
     v_constraint text;
  BEGIN
     LOOP  -- endless loop until INSERT or UPDATE succeeds
        BEGIN
           INSERT INTO ...;

           EXIT;  -- leave loop if INSERT succeeds
        EXCEPTION
           WHEN unique_violation THEN
              GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_constraint := CONSTRAINT_NAME;
        END;

        CASE v_constraint
           WHEN 'constraint_name_1' THEN 
              UPDATE ...;
           WHEN 'constraint_name_2' THEN
              UPDATE ...;
        END CASE;

        EXIT WHEN FOUND;  -- leave loop if UPDATE changed a row
     END LOOP;
  END;
  ```